# Can I tell which email accounts are linked to the mobile device?

Tags: android, ios, email, mobile, windows-phone

I have a mobile app which as part of registration sends an email to verify that the user owns the email address they signed up with. On a mobile, this is slightly annoying because they need to leave the app into their mail app to click on the link and then go back into the app to finish the sign-up.

If I can tell, from the app, which email accounts are already "linked" to the phone, I can bypass this whole step if they register one of these email addresses since I know that they will have access to the email app on the mobile (and these apps never require a separate password once they are linked).

This is for an Android app but if it is only possible on another platform, that might also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get the account that is linked using the AccountManager in android, try the following code:

```
private void getAccounts(){

        final AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
        final Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        final int size = accounts.length;
        names = new String[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          names[i] = accounts[i].name;
        }

    }
```